# Grid where children are all same width

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a `<Grid>` with six children (`<Grid item>`). Each of the six items has the property `xs = {1.5}` so they each take up the same amount of space.

Within each `<Grid item>` are various input fields. How can I get the input field to take up the full width of the `<Grid item>`?

Would I have to pass something to the children through the `sx` prop? I've tried some flex properties without any luck so far. I can use something other than `Grid` - I'm new to React and this is just what I've been trying to work with so far.

Below is the code. I removed things like `value = 'something'` or `id = 'myID'` and left only the relevant info for readability.

```
<Container maxWidth = 'false' sx = {{mx: 1, my: 1}} disableGutters>    
    <Grid container sx = {{border: '1px solid white'}}>
        <Grid item container direction = 'row' sx = {{my: 1}}>
            <Grid item xs = {1.5}>
                <TextField label = '1'/>
            </Grid>
                    
            <Grid item xs = {1.5}>
                <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel>2</InputLabel>
                    <Select>
                        <MenuItem>...</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
                    
            <Grid item xs = {1.5}>
                <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel>3</InputLabel>
                    <Select>
                       <MenuItem>...</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid> 

            <Grid item xs = {1.5} sx = {{border: '1px dotted red'}}>
                <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel >4</InputLabel>
                    <Select>
                        <MenuItem>...</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>
                    
            <Grid item xs = {1.5}>
                <FormControl>
                    <InputLabel>5</InputLabel>
                     <Select>
                         <MenuItem>...</MenuItem>
                    </Select>
                </FormControl>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs = {1.5}>
                <TextField label = '6'/>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `width` or any other css property to `FormControl` or any other Mui Component using `sx` props. check https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/ for more details.

```
<FormControl sx={{width:"100%"}}>
...
</FormControl>
```